# Creating a local singleton correctly Obj C. (Not a shared global Singleton)

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I'm designing a class that MUST only have one instance of itself at any time. I'm trying to avoid the common pattern of a shared singleton that is globally accessible, I only want a local object that can only be allocated once but can also be set to nil. How does this look?

```
static BOOL isInitialized = NO;

@implementation Single



-(instancetype) init
{
  if (isInitialized == NO)
  {
    if (self = [super init])
    {

    }        
    isInitialized = YES;
    return self;
  }
  else
  {
    NSAssert(FALSE, @"Only one instance allowed");
    return nil;
  }    
}


-(void) dealloc
{
    isInitialized = NO;
}

@end
```

I'm not concerned about thread safety as I only plan to use class on main thread. When the object is deferrenced the overridden dealloc should ensure a new instance can be created. Anybody see any issues with this or improvements? Cheers

Comment: why not do a static field and keep the object there. return it from init instead of nsassert

Comment: If I return a static object it cannot be automatically deallocated. I don't need the object to remain in memory for the lifetime of the app.

Answer (score 0):

It's a corner case, but as written if the call to `[super init]` fails then `isInitialized` will be set to `YES` *(Note that in this case the passed in `self` is deallocated **before** the flag is set)* - this means that no instance of the class will ever be created as there is nothing to deallocate to reset your flag. Maybe you want:

```
if (self = [super init])
{
   isInitialized = YES;
}        
return self;
```

Otherwise, given that you are not concerned over thread safety and you want a second allocation attempt to be a failure (your use of `NSAssert`), your code looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your method looks cleaner . But If [super init] retuned nil then the reference count would be nil and dealloc would be called I think retuning isInitialized to NO anyway.

Comment: @Titch - Not quite, added a note to the answer to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be better to return the existing instance instead of crashing?

```
@implementation Single

- (instancetype)init {
    static __weak Single *weakInstance;

    Single *strongInstance = weakInstance;
    if (strongInstance) {
        self = strongInstance;
    } else {
        if (self = [super init]) {
            weakInstance = self;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

You don't need to do anything special in `dealloc` because the system will clear the `__weak` reference automatically when the instance is deallocated.

Comment: Thanks Rob thats a neat design and I prefer not having to override dealloc. I plan to use the class to hold important state information and only wanted to have one object, I could then pass this to specific objects that could change that state data. I was concerned that having a shared object would open the possibility of the wrong object having access. With a local object I would have tighter control. (or maybe I'm just being pedantic)

Answer (score 0):

@Rob

Can the strong reference be removed from your method?

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    static __weak id weakInstance;

    if (weakInstance)
    {
        self = weakInstance;
    }
    else
    {
        if (self = [super init])
        {
            weakInstance = self;
        }
    }
return self;
```

}

seems to work.